# Generating Trigrams with Gensim's Phraser Package in Python

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, phrase

I have the following code snippet which I created with the help of [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/unsupervised-sentiment-analysis-a38bf1906483) tutorial for unsupervised sentiment analysis purposes:

```
sent = [row for row in file_model.message]
phrases = Phrases(sent, min_count=1, progress_per=50000)
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
sentences = bigram[sent]
sentences[1]

file_export = file_model.copy()
file_export['old_message'] = file_export.message
file_export.old_message = file_export.old_message.str.join(' ')
file_export.message = file_export.message.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(bigram[x]))

file_export.to_csv('cleaned_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

Since now I want to have bigrams as well as trigrams, I tried it by adjusting it to:

```
sent = [row for row in file_model.message]
phrases = Phrases(sent, min_count=1, progress_per=50000)
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
trigram = Phraser(bigram[phrases])
sentences = trigram[sent]
sentences[1]

file_export = file_model.copy()
file_export['old_message'] = file_export.message
file_export.old_message = file_export.old_message.str.join(' ')
file_export.message = file_export.message.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(trigram[x]))

file_export.to_csv('cleaned_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

But when I run this, I get **`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`** which I assume refers to my adjustment to `trigram = Phraser(bigram[phrases])`. I am using `gensim 4.1.2`.
Unfortunately, I have no computer science background and solutions I find online don't help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general matter, it's best if you include in your question (by later editing if necessary) *the entire multiline error message you received*, including any 'traceback' showing involved filenames, line-numbers, & lines-of-source-code. That helps potential answerers focus on exactly where things are going wrong.

Also, beware that many of the tutorials at 'towardsdatascience.com' are of very poor quality. I can't see the exact one you've linked without registering (which I'd rather not do), but from your code excerpts, I already see a few issues of varying severity for what you're trying to do:

- (fatal) If you want to apply the `Phrases` algorithm more than once, to compose up phrases longes than bigrams, you can't reuse the model trained for bigrams. You need to train a new model for each new level-of-combination, on the *output* of the prior model. That is, the input to the trigrams `Phrases` model (which must be trained) for trigrams must be the results of applying the bigram model, so it sees a mixture of the original unigrams & now-combined bigrams.
- (unwise) Generally, using a low `min_count=1` on these sorts of data-hungry models can easily backfire. They need many examples for their statistical-methods to do anything sensible; discarding the rarest words usually helps to speed processing, shrink the models, & work mainly on tokens where there's enough examples to do something possibly sensible. (With very few, or only 1, usage examples, results may seem somewhat random/arbitrary.)
- (a bit oudated but not a big problem) In Gensim 4+, the `Phraser` utiity class – which just exists to optimized the `Phrases` model a bit, when you're sure you're done training/tuning – has been renamed `FrozenPhrases`. (The old name still works, but this is an indication the tutorial hasn't been recently refreshed.)

And in general, beware: without a lot of data, the output of any number of `Phrases` applications may not be strong. And in all cases, it may not 'look right' to human sensibilities – because it's pure statistical, co-occurrence driven. (Though, even if its output looks weird, it will sometimes help on certain info-retrieval/classification tasks, as it manages to create useful new features that are different than the unigrams alone.)

My suggestions would be:

- only add any `Phrases` combinations after things are working without, so you can compare results & see if it's helping.
- start with bigrams only, and be sure via careful review or rigorous scoring that's working/helping
- if you need another level of combination, add that later, & ensure the trigram `Phrases` is initialized with the already-bigram-combined texts.

(Unfortunately, I can't find an example of two-level `Phrases` use in the current Gensim docs – I think some old examples were edited-out in doc simplification work. But there are a couple examples of it not being used all-wrong in the project's testing source code – search the file https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/test/test_phrases.py for `trigram`. But remember those aren't best practices, either, as focused minimal tests.)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer! It really helps me.  Just one more question:
1
Lets say I want to try out the model with unigrams only, how can I do that? By simply taking a code like: 
`sent = [row for row in file_model.message]
phrases = Phrases(sent, min_count=1, progress_per=50000)
sentences = phrases[sent]
sentences[1]`

instead of the originial one?

`sent = [row for row in file_model.message]
phrases = Phrases(sent, min_count=1, progress_per=50000)
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
sentences = bigram[sent]
sentences[1]`

Comment: If you simply want to apply `Phrases` once, to the original unigrams, then get a transformed corpus where some of the statistically-interesting word-pairs are combined into `word1_word2` bigrams, your code looks about right. But (1) above comment re `min_count` still applies; (2) the real test is whether the output sequence includes text changed the way you expect - when you try it, does it look right?; (3) the Gensim docs includes model code for that simple application: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html